# Is it possible to derive Reciprocal Pythagoras Theorem from Stewart's theorem with other additional relations?

Tags: systems-of-equations

Consider the following diagram.

[image]

The Reciprocal Pythagorean Theorem (RPT) below
$$
\frac{1}{t^2} = \frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}
$$
can be easily obtained from
\begin{cases}
bc=at\\
a^2=b^2+c^2
\end{cases}

I want to get the RPT from Stewart's theorem
$$
a(t^2+a_1a_2)=b^2a_2+c^2a_1
$$
and from other additional relation below.
\begin{cases}
a^2=b^2+c^2\\
a= a_1+a_2 \\
t^2=a_1 a_2
\end{cases}

## Question

Is it possible to get RPT from Stewart's theorem plus the additional relations given above?

Comment: Sorry, but with $a_1=0,$ your expression equals $\frac1{b^2},$ and with $a_2=0,$ it equals $\frac1{c^2}.$ I hope you can't manipulate it to the extent that it is the sum of both.

Comment: It's your equation, not mine.

Comment: Please, read the meaning of "=" in mathematics.

Comment: If you really think that your "real problem" overrules the laws of mathematics, I'm not sure you can get help, *here*.

Comment: Do you allow to use $bc=ta$?

Comment: $bc=ta$ makes Stewart's no longer useful. :-)

Comment: Is Stewart useful at all in this case?  I don't get your intention.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: I rewrote my question to be clearer.

Comment: It's close but unfortunately not possible, because $t^2 = a_1 a_2$ doesn't _quite_ guarantee that the cevian divides the triangle into two similar ones. Your system has one extra solution, $a_1 = a_2 = t$.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying we get $$(b^2+c^2)(a_1^2a_2+a_1a_2^2)-a_1c^4-a_2b^4=0$$